# Gantt Chart Zoom in function is possible in Splunk?

Tags: javascript, css, splunk, gantt-chart, timeserieschart

Hello I have a question

I made a gantt chart using custom viz in splunk like this here.
https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1741/

It's app is very nice so many data visualization I think.

But How can I using zoom in/out function in this apps.

Need modified apps add to zoom in/out function?

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to contact the developer to modify the app to allow zooming in and out. Or ad the source is available, add that function yourself. It doesn't look like that feature is supported currently

In general, you would probably like to decrease the time selected in order to zoom in to a particular timeframe